# Why am I getting "expected expression pylance"? Whats wrong with my elseif statements?

Tags: python

Absolutely stuck on what I'm doing wrong here. I've set everything up seemingly correctly unless I'm missing a small error. Can anyone provide some guidance on what I'm doing wrong? Are my elseif statements incorrect? I've tried changing the elseif statements to other options and still stuck. From what I can see looking over proper documentation everything seems to be setup correctly.

```
candy = {
    "m&m": 1.99,
    "butterfingers": 1.25,
    "skittles": 2.99,
    "snickers": 1.3
}

inventory = [5, 10, 2, 3]


qty1 = int(input("how many M&M's ? "))
if qty1 < 1:
    print(f"Sorry invalid input")
qty1 =0
elif qty1 > inventory[0]:
    print(f"Sorry we don't have that many...giving you {inventory[0]} instead")
qty1 = inventory[0] 
    inventory[0] = 0 
else:
inventory[0] = inventory[0] - qty1 


qty2 = int(input("how many butterfingers ? "))
if qty2 < 1:
    print(f"Sorry invalid input")
qty2 =0 
elif qty2 > inventory[1]:
    print(f"Sorry we don't have that many...giving you {inventory[1]} instead")
qty2 = inventory[1] 
    inventory[1] = 0 
else:
inventory[1] = inventory[1] - qty2 



qty3 = int(input("how many skittles ? "))
if qty3 < 1:
    print(f"Sorry invalid input")
qty3 =0 
elif qty3 > inventory[2]:
    print(f"Sorry we don't have that many...giving you {inventory[2]} instead")
qty3 = inventory[2] 
    inventory[2] = 0 
else:
inventory[2] = inventory[2] - qty3 



qty4 = int(input("how many snickers ? "))
if qty4 < 1:
    print(f"Sorry invalid input")
qty4 =0 
elif qty4 > inventory[3]:
    print(f"Sorry we don't have that many...giving you {inventory[3]} instead")
qty4 = inventory[3] 
    inventory[3] = 0 
else:
inventory[3] = inventory[3] - qty4 


cost = qty1 * candy["m&m"] + qty2 * candy["butterfingers"] + qty3 * candy["skittles"] + qty4 * candy["snickers"]
print("thanks for the order.....")
print()

print(f"your cost will be ${cost:2.2f}")

print(f"our new inventory is {inventory}")
```

Comment: Also you should have nothing in between your if and elif statements

Comment: You should keep your whole block `if` block indented before the `elif`. If you have a non-indented line python will see that as the end of the `if`.

Comment: This is an indentation problem. For example, I'm seeing the line below the `else` block is not indented.

Comment: Is the indentation in the post the same as your code as a few things will cause errors (mainly unindenting before the elif and having no else values)

Comment: If that's literally your code, then your indentation is wrong.  The lines assigning to `qty1` and `qty2` in the if/elif need to be shifted right by one indent.

Comment: Please find a book or tutorial on Python and gain a solid understanding of proper indentation and of `if/elif/else` statements.  If what you're trying to run is indented differently than what you've shown us here, FIX IT.  You say "From what I can see looking over proper documentation "...you're obviously not looking closely enough.

Comment: No problem, next time try to include the error message that you receive as it's most of the times informative enough to be able to identify and fix the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

**Problem 1**: You have statements in between `if` and `elif` blocks. To fix this change:

```
if qty1 < 1:
    print(f"Sorry invalid input")
qty1 = 0
elif qty1 > inventory[0]:
```

to:

```
if qty1 < 1:
    print(f"Sorry invalid input")
elif qty1 > inventory[0]:
```

**Problem 2**: You have the `else` block that is not indented, to fix this change:

```
else:
inventory[0] = inventory[0] - qty1
```

to:

```
else:
    inventory[0] = inventory[0] - qty1
```

If you fix these problems in all sections of the code you should get the following code with no errors:

```
candy = {
    "m&m": 1.99,
    "butterfingers": 1.25,
    "skittles": 2.99,
    "snickers": 1.3
}

inventory = [5, 10, 2, 3]

qty1 = int(input("how many M&M's ? "))
if qty1 < 1:
    print(f"Sorry invalid input")
elif qty1 > inventory[0]:
    print(f"Sorry we don't have that many...giving you {inventory[0]} instead")
    qty1 = inventory[0] 
    inventory[0] = 0 
else:
    inventory[0] = inventory[0] - qty1 

qty2 = int(input("how many butterfingers ? "))
if qty2 < 1:
    print(f"Sorry invalid input")
elif qty2 > inventory[1]:
    print(f"Sorry we don't have that many...giving you {inventory[1]} instead")
    qty2 = inventory[1] 
    inventory[1] = 0 
else:
    inventory[1] = inventory[1] - qty2 

qty3 = int(input("how many skittles ? "))
if qty3 < 1:
    print(f"Sorry invalid input")
elif qty3 > inventory[2]:
    print(f"Sorry we don't have that many...giving you {inventory[2]} instead")
    qty3 = inventory[2] 
    inventory[2] = 0 
else:
    inventory[2] = inventory[2] - qty3 

qty4 = int(input("how many snickers ? "))
if qty4 < 1:
    print(f"Sorry invalid input")
elif qty4 > inventory[3]:
    print(f"Sorry we don't have that many...giving you {inventory[3]} instead")
    qty4 = inventory[3] 
    inventory[3] = 0 
else:
    inventory[3] = inventory[3] - qty4 

cost = qty1 * candy["m&m"] + qty2 * candy["butterfingers"] + qty3 * candy["skittles"] + qty4 * candy["snickers"]
print("thanks for the order.....")
print()

print(f"your cost will be ${cost:2.2f}")

print(f"our new inventory is {inventory}")
```

Comment: Wow, it was just indentation. I'm a doofus. When transferring the program from one file to another I messed it all up. Appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help